# Huge XHR latency to retrieve model data for controller

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, angularjs

I have a simple controller, which makes an ajax call to retrieve it's model (a 4.5k json containing a 2d array). I use this controller to create a combo which displays a series of labels, the html is:

```
<select data-ng-controller="CGSimpleXHRComboController"
        data-ng-init="getData(MY_URL)">
    <option data-ng-value="item[0]"
            data-ng-repeat="item in items"
            data-ng-cloak>
          {$ item[1] $}
    </option>
</select>
```

And this is my controller:

```
angular.module('CGSimpleXHRComboController', []).
    controller('CGSimpleXHRComboController', ['$scope', '$http', 'CGLogger',
        function($scope, $http, CGLogger) {

        "use strict";

        $scope.__successHandler = function(data) {
            CGLogger.debug('Data has been retrieved');
            $scope.items = data.data;
        };

        $scope.__failHandler = function() {
            CGLogger.error(arguments[0]);
        };

        $scope.getData = function(url) {
            CGLogger.debug('Retrieving combo data from "{0}"', url);
            $http.get(url).
                success(function(data) {
                    $scope.__successHandler(data);
                }).
                error(function(msg) {
                    $scope.__failHandler.apply($scope, arguments);
                });
        };
    }]);
```

The code works, but it takes several seconds to fill the combo with the data in the json.
By analyzing the XHR call, Chrome says it has **3.8 seconds** of latency!
If I run `jQuery.get(MY_URL)` in the console, the response is blazing fast: **40ms** only of latency! So... what's going on here? (I tried to use jQuery to make the call in the controller but the latency remains huge... so the problem is not the ajax call itself)

Comment: I suspect it is the rendering that is causing the delay. Can you confirm by measuring the time between the log statements - `'Retrieving combo data...'` and `'Data has been retrieved'`? If it is the rendering, can you replace the `<option ng-repeat>` with (the more appropriate in my opinion) `<select ng-options>`?

Answer (score 0):

OMG, just realized what is the problem and it's totally unrelated to AngularJS or my code implementation! I'm using **Django** for my app and locally I installed **django-toolbar**, which is an app designed to provide app tracing and debugging tools (it displays query executed, loaded templates and so on...) perhaps its js files interferes with mine and the result is a sucky client side behavior. By removing that app now the latency is only **10ms**! Amazing :)